# Cursor.execute data adds single quotes marks and breaks query that contains IN(1,2) statement with mysql in python

Tags: python, mysql, variables, select, cursor

thanks for reading.
I have an issue trying to send a variable to cursor.execute(query,variable). Query contains IN (%s) stament and variable contains ints comma separated. 
Problem occurs when pythons execute apparently adds single quote marks to variable. It breaks query. So...
How can I override this behavior to discard quotation marks?

**query**:
review_authors=

```
SELECT   autor.id, autor.escuela, autor.nombre, count(*) 
FROM     autor, cita, obra 
WHERE    obra.autor=autor.id 
AND      cita.obra=obra.id 
AND      cita.id in ( %s ) 
GROUP BY autor.id, autor.escuela, autor.nombre 
ORDER BY autor.nombre ASC;
```

**data**:

```
citaid=request.cookies.get("idNote")
```

**cursor.execute**:

```
Cursor.execute(review_authors, citaid)
```

**informed error**:

> C:\Users\sebap\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1292, "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '5302,5303,354,501'")
>     result = self._query(query)

thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is put placeholder `%s` in your query.
Then the variables will go into their appropriate places.

```
citaid=request.cookies.get("idNote")
placeholders = ",".join(['%s']*len(citaid)) 
review_authors = """SELECT autor.id, autor.escuela, autor.nombre, COUNT(*) 
                    FROM autor, cita, obra 
                    WHERE obra.autor=autor.id 
                        AND cita.obra=obra.id 
                        AND cita.id in ({}) 
                    GROUP BY autor.id, autor.escuela, autor.nombre 
                    ORDER BY autor.nombre ASC;""".format(placeholders)
Cursor.execute(review_authors, citaid)
```

Comment: Thank you Adam, you are a very nice person. You answered really fast and were right. Your words were very usefull to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Seba: you're very welcome. I wish you happy coding.